# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, ssl, devops

[image]

При запуске локального проекта на http://localhost:3001 в гугл хром возникает ошибка, при этом в режиме инкогнито все норм. Проблема именно в Хроме вне зависимости от ОС. Ни один из найденных в гугле способов решения проблемы не дал результата(
Frontend, билдится через webpack.

Comment: Что за локальный проект? Фронт, бэк? На чём написан? Как собирается?

Comment: Фронт, билда компилиться вебпаком, проект на ReactJs

Comment: Значит, наверное, вы однажды случайно (или не случайно) открыли localhost в режиме https и браузер запомнил это

Comment: webpack запускает проект по http, но гугл хром автоматически перекидывает именно этот только урл на https

Comment: В сафари и mozilla все норм при этом кэш конечно чистил. Нужен именно хром из за react dev tools и redux dev tools

Answer (score 2):

Еще один эффективный способ решения данной проблемы:
chrome://net-internals/#hsts
[image: Добавит localhost in Domain]

Answer (score 0):

в итоге для сработала команда `open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security`
(Для macos)